# A question with HTML unescaped tags in the title breaks rendering on multiple pages

Tags: bug

This question: [Jupyter syntax highlight in <code> environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892934/jupyter-syntax-highlight-in-code-environment) breaks rendering as of September 1st. It was displayed ok previously when I left a comment there seven days ago.

[image]

[image]

It seems distinct from recently reported [Adding HTML tags or HTML-tag-like to a title, breaks rendering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411177/specific-question-breaks-rendering-both-of-question-itself-and-of-the-list-of-q)

Comment: Well, apparently you can reproduce this on this question too ;) I did not mean to do that (which is why I added backticks, but apparently this does not help)